# How do I create a responsive fluid CSS grid

Tags: css

I am having a bit of difficulty understanding how to place elements depending on the media size. For example, on mobile, I would like the elements stacked in a single column as numbered; an article, the ad, another article, then the article teasers.

I understand how to do this with CSS grid if the elements were to start at a specific row in a grid (as shown in [Mozilla Developer docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Realizing_common_layouts_using_CSS_Grid_Layout)), but the demonstration does not show how actual content would look inside the sections when I need the content to flow from the top of the document.

I'm probably expecting too much, but is this possible using CSS grid? In the past, I could do this using React, but very hackish with conditional renders and window width queries.

```css
        html,body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .sm-hide {
            /* these eleements aren't shown in our mobile-first layout */
            display: none;
        }

        .article {
            background-color: beige;
            margin: 5px;
            height: 285px;
        }

        .ad {
            background-color: beige;
            margin: 5px;
            height: 100px;
        }

        .more {
            background-color: beige;
            margin: 5px;
            height: 300px;
        }

        aside {
            background-color: lightblue;
            /* name the area */
            grid-area: aside;
        }

        main {
            background-color: lightseagreen;
            grid-area: main;
        }

        footer {
            background-color: lightcoral;
            grid-area: footer;
        }

        wrapper {
            /* set up the grid */
            display: grid;
            height: 100%;
            /* specify a static value and use fractional units to take the remainder */
            grid-template-rows: 1fr 50px;
            /* the 1fr is assumed and is not necessary, but for demo */
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            /* specify what element gets each grid area */
            grid-template-areas: "main" "footer";
        }

        @media (min-width: 600px) {
            .sm-hide {
                /* show the elements on larger displays */
                display: initial;
            }
            wrapper {
                grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
                grid-template-areas: "main aside" "footer footer";
            }
        }
```

```html
    <wrapper>
        <aside class="sm-hide">aside
            <div class="ad">
                ad 2
            </div>
            <div class="more">
                article teasers 4
            </div>
        </aside>
        <main>main
            <div class="article">
                article 1
            </div>
            <div class="article">
                article 3
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer>footer</footer>
    </wrapper>
```

Comment: I'm working on it, please give me about 10 minutes :)

Comment: I didn't mean to use wrapper; habit from using styled-components with React (const Wrapper = styled.div`/* some css */`). I meant to use div class="wrapper". Could you show me the way using your recommendations?

Comment: I have a solution based on the answer @DomenikReitzner provided. Should I post an answer to my own question, as the answer provided is incomplete?

Comment: Good idea. Didn't get around to refine my answer today.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are missing the viewport. You might have it in your full html.

My "solution" works (kind of), but I would think about restructuring your html markup in a way that you don't use wrappers.

Beside using `<article>` I would use `aside.ad` and `aside.more` to get rid of encapsulation. Works way better in grid.

Feel free to ask some more, if anything is unclear.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

article {
  background-color: beige;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 285px;
}

.ad {
  background-color: beige;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100px;
}

.more {
  background-color: beige;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 300px;
}

aside {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: contents;
}

.ad {
  grid-area: ad;
}

.more {
  grid-area: more;
}

main {
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  display: contents;
}

main article:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: first-article
}

main article:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: second-article
}

footer {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  grid-area: footer;
}

wrapper {
  /* set up the grid */
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  /* specify a static value and use fractional units to take the remainder */
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto 50px;
  /* the 1fr is assumed and is not necessary, but for demo */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  /* specify what element gets each grid area */
  grid-template-areas: "first-article" "ad" "second-article" "more" "footer";
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "main aside" "footer footer";
  }
  aside {
    /* name the area */
    grid-area: aside;
  }
  main {
    grid-area: main;
  }
  main,
  aside {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<wrapper>
  <aside class="sm-hide">aside
    <div class="ad">
      ad 2
    </div>
    <div class="more">
      article teasers 4
    </div>
  </aside>
  <main>main
    <article>
      article 1
    </article>
    <article>
      article 3
    </article>
  </main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</wrapper>
```

Answer (score 0):

The secret ingredient was the `display: contents` suggested by Domenik, and explained in the [Mozilla Developer docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Relationship_of_Grid_Layout#Grid_and_display_contents).

```css
        * {
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        body {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-areas: "as1" "ad" "as2" "tsr";
        }

        /* this is key to reordering the elements */
        main,
        aside {
            display: contents;
        }


        main {
            background-color: darkslateblue;
        }

        aside {
            background-color: darkgreen;
        }

        .teasers {
            background-color: blanchedalmond;
            min-height: 200px;
            grid-area: tsr;
        }

        .as1 {
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            grid-area: as1;
            min-height: 300px;
        }

        .as2 {
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            grid-area: as2;
            min-height: 250px;
        }

        .ad {
            background-color: aqua;
            grid-area: ad;
        }

        @media (min-width: 400px) {
            body {
                grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
                grid-template-areas: "as1 ad" "as2 tsr";
            }
            main,
            aside {
                display: initial;
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <section class="as1">
            first article space
        </section>
        <section class="as2">
            second article space
        </section>
    </main>
    <aside>
        <div class="ad">
            ad space
        </div>
        <section class="teasers">
            more stuff
        </section>
    </aside>

    <script></script>
</body>

</html>
```